# fine upload validation set

Tags: javascript, validation, types, fine-uploader

**I´m using the** [Fine Upload-Plugin](http://fineuploader.com/).

I want to upload .docx-files to my application ... only .docx-files.

Surely this is easy to handle with a query, like

```
if (extension == "docx") 
 upload something
```

But I saw a field in which you can specify a data type like "All types" or "All images".

**Where can i add/manipulate this validation?**

I tried the acceptFiles-options, but this only prevent uploads.
I want to give the user the possibility to show .docx-files only.

**HTML-Code:**

```html
<div id="manual-fine-uploader"></div>
   <div id="triggerUpload" class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-top: 10px;display:none">
   <i class="icon-upload icon-white"></i> Datei einfügen
</div>
<div id="uploadNewFile"></div>
```

**JS-Code**

```js
$("#uploadNewFile").fineUploader({
    element: document.getElementById('manual-fine-uploader'),
    request: {
        endpoint: 'Upload.aspx'
    },
    autoUpload: true,
    //Part, that may be important
    ///MEME-Type: docx
    acceptFiles: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document",
    allowedExtensions: ["docx"],
    //Endpart
    maxConnections: 1,
    multiple: false,
    chunking: {
        enabled: true
    },
    resume: {
        enabled: true
    },
    text: {
        uploadButton: 'Datei hochladen'
    }
});
```

**EDIT:**

Maybe the Question isnt clear enough:

I need a specific filter within the select-file-dialog.

Like the standard "images only" or "all types" etc..

**How to add these kind of filter?**

[Here you see the select](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DTrBE.png)

Comment: While you can validate extension on the client side, its not totallt reliable. You'd better validate a file on the server-side as well

Comment: Edited an link to a picture

Answer (score 3):

Your `allowedExtensions` and `acceptFiles` options are not in the correct place.  Your code should look like this:

```
$("#uploadNewFile").fineUploader({
    element: document.getElementById('manual-fine-uploader'),
    request: {
        endpoint: 'Upload.aspx'
    },
    validation: {
        acceptFiles: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document",
        allowedExtensions: ["docx"]
    },
    maxConnections: 1,
    multiple: false,
    chunking: {
        enabled: true
    },
    resume: {
        enabled: true
    },
    text: {
        uploadButton: 'Datei hochladen'
    }
});
```

Please see the [`validation` option in the documentation](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/options.html#validation) for more details, along with the [validation feature page](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/features/validation.html).

Also, if you are using Fine Uploader 4.x, the `text.uploadButton` option was removed as part of the templating redesign.  In 4.x and newer, you can specify the button name, among other things, in a template you declare in your markup.

Finally, I removed the `autoUpload` option from your configuration, as you were setting it to the default value.  No need to declare it in that case.

Comment: This change create alerts in case of wrong files, which I dont need. I check the extension inside the aspx. I need a filter to select docx-files.

Comment: Then you can either override the [showMessage option](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/options.html#showMessage) or, instead of using the `validation` option, validate the files yourself via a `validate` or `validateBatch` event handler.  See the documentation for details.